# Getting Obstructing Warning with .pbx workspace file svn local copy.

Tags: xcode, svn

I am working with svn server to upload my updated file to server. But at last when i upload latest copy to server at that time i get **Obstructing** warning in my below given Xcode project file. I dont know what to do for this please help me to get it out.

Following is my file which is giving me **Obstructing** warning.

1. UserInterfaceState.xuserstate.
2. dat0b55.00f

When i  search this file in finder it give me location of xproject workspace.path as below:
MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/myworkspace.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserdatad.

I can't understand how to remove this warning. I can't remove project and upload fresh copy because it is on client server.
So, If it possible please help me to solve it manually without deleting project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by replacing all required files from my back up.You can get above file from .pbx extract your project file with show in package content and replace it.It's work for me fine.